# How to access really nested JSON dicts?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

After obtaining the JSON data through data scraping a web, I'm trying to trasnform it as part of an ETL. But the problem is that the JSON is really nested. My objective is getting data in pandas table/df format:

[image: pandas dataframe example]

I already used json_normalize and read documentation but really couldn't make it work since, after creating the json_normalize, the dataframe looks like this:

[image: json viewer]

I think it will be better posting 2 more pics of a json viewer and the actual json, in case someone can help me out with this topic since it's driving me crazy:

[image: json_normalize]

```json
{
     "group":3,
      "acc":"Yum.8039",
      "profession":"Mechanist",
      "isPoV":false,
      "isCommander":false,
      "l1Set":["Rifle"],
      "l2Set":[],
      "a1Set":[],
      "a2Set":[],
      "colTarget":"rgb(208,156,89)",
      "colCleave":"rgb(158,119,68)",
      "colTotal":"rgb(109,83,48)",
      "isFake":false,
      "notInSquad":false,
      "uniqueID":52,
      "name":"F L O R I � N",
      "tough":0,
      "condi":0,
      "conc":0,
      "heal":0,
      "icon":"https://wiki.guildwars2.com/images/thumb/8/8a/Mechanist_tango_icon_200px.png/20px-Mechanist_tango_icon_200px.png",
      "health":-1,
      "minions":[
          {
              "id":79,
              "name":"Jade Mech CJ-1"
          },
          {
              "id":122,"name":
              "Mark I Golem"}
      ],
      "details":{
          "dmgDistributions":[
              {
                  "contributedDamage":2881217,
                  "contributedBreakbarDamage":0.0,
                  "contributedShieldDamage":0,
                  "totalDamage":5174108,
                  "totalBreakbarDamage":300.0,
                  "totalCasting":163564,
                  "distribution":[
                      [
                          false,59562,58168,4291,10176,7,7,7,3,0,0.0,0.0,0,58168,7,0,0,0.0
                      ],
                      [
                          false,6003,738013,0,4372,164,240,235,157,0,1.663,1.193,0,733712,254,98611,0,0.0
                      ],
                      [
                          false,68121,397981,0,5747,0,96,96,64,0,0.0,0.0,0,397981,102,0,0,0.0
                      ],
                      [
                          true,736,107737,6,1622,0,176,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0,196,0,0,0.0
                      ],
                      [
                          false,29889,229776,0,8299,0,37,37,23,0,0.0,0.0,0,229776,37,0,0,0.0
                      ],
                      [
                          false,6004,66664,3660,7118,12,12,12,8,0,0.0,0.0,0,66664,12,5780,0,0.0
                      ],
                      [
                          false,6154,109152,6475,14379,22,11,11,4,0,0.0,0.0,0,109152,11,6224,0,0.0
                      ]
                  ]
              }
          ]
      } 
}
```

My objective is creating a dataframe as showed on the first pic containing players group, name, acc and dps from phase 1, 2 and 3 that can be found inside the full JSON (I just uploaded part of it as it is quite huge). The actual phase dmg is founded for all players in:

```
phase1_dps = data['phases'][1]['dpsStats'][0:10] 
phase2_dps = data['phases'][6]['dpsStats'][0:10] 
phase3_dps = data['phases'][12]['dpsStats'][0:10]
```

But, this same dmg can be founded in ['details'][dmgDistributions][0]:

```
> "details":{
         "dmgDistributions":[
             {
                 "contributedDamage":2881217,
                 "contributedBreakbarDamage":0.0,
                 "contributedShieldDamage":0,
                 "totalDamage":5174108,
                 "totalBreakbarDamage":300.0,
                 "totalCasting":163564
```

The part I cannot access is the dmg, since in the second pic that column appear as detail.dmgDistribution

To summarize, the dataframe should be dsiplaying a frame like the one on the first pic but instead of tough, condi, conc and heal, it should show the dps done per phase on each player, as a rough sketch, dps should be like this:

[image: sketch]

Any tip or information would be great, I thought on just trying to get the info through JSON queries in case there isn't any other options. So, thanks in advance to anyone helping out!

Comment: What is the final result that you desire?

Comment: I would like to create a dataframe containing the players names, group, acc and dps from phase 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: phase1_dps = data['phases'][1]['dpsStats'][0:10]
    phase2_dps = data['phases'][6]['dpsStats'][0:10]
    phase3_dps = data['phases'][12]['dpsStats'][0:10] This is a query for a for loop getting that data

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show that detail.

Comment: The first picture isn't helpful, it is just confusing since it has nothing to do with the actual data. you just want to have a normal df right ? So for this group 3 you want to have `"group":3,"acc":"Yum.8039"` and both names which are inside of minions? what about your 2nd comment. I can't see `phases`  or `dpsStats` . We can't answer the question like that. Please add some desired output which fits the same example data you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not quite clear to me how the data you showed us lead to an output you want, but since you asked for some hints, here is how you might come forward with your goal.

Load the data from json:

```
with open('your_json.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then use `pd.json_normalize` to get this the columns `['id', 'name', 'group', 'acc', 'details.dmgDistributions']`. The first two column are from record_path, the rest from meta.

```
out = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['minions'], meta = ['group', 'acc', ['details', 'dmgDistributions']])
out
```

Output:

```
    id            name group       acc  \
0   79  Jade Mech CJ-1     3  Yum.8039   
1  122    Mark I Golem     3  Yum.8039   

                            details.dmgDistributions  
0  {'contributedDamage': 2881217, 'contributedBre...  
1  {'contributedDamage': 2881217, 'contributedBre...
```

Now you change the dicts in `details.dmgDistributions` to own columns and join it back to the current df `out`:

```
out.join(out.pop('details.dmgDistributions').apply(pd.Series))
```

Output:

```
    id            name group       acc  contributedDamage  contributedBreakbarDamage  contributedShieldDamage  totalDamage  totalBreakbarDamage  totalCasting  distribution
0   79  Jade Mech CJ-1     3  Yum.8039            2881217                        0.0                        0      5174108                300.0        163564  [[False, 59562, 58168, 4291...],...]
1  122    Mark I Golem     3  Yum.8039            2881217                        0.0                        0      5174108                300.0        163564  [[False, 59562, 58168, 4291...],...]
```

Don't know if you need to split all the row values in `distribution` but if you need to, have a look at [`pd.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: I might had a hard time to explain the problem , but with this answer I see some things I can try that I wasn't doing the right way. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. That's why I posted the answer, maybe you see something you didn't try. For the future, if you ask a question, post your example data, then explain your goal and then show the desired output for that specific example where names and numbers fit. Like that, we know where you want to go. For the output it doesn't matter if that is a df or a screenshot of an excel table you created by hand or a hand drawn table.